# Avoiding children nodes appear at same or upper level of parent level

Tags: c#

I am constructing a map. for that I need to assign a level to each node of the map and I need this levels to be automatically generated.

Currently I have relation between the nodes. (relation as in parent-children)
In the given example there altogether 23 nodes.

I don't want any children to be at the same level as parent or above the parent level.

I currently have the two dataTables. First contains the node ids and second one contains the levels corresponding to the node ids.

How can I make any adjustment in the below code  so that any child does not come on the same level or above the level of its parent?

Output of the below code is x and y coordinates of the nodes.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace coordinatesGeneration
{
    class Program
    {
        internal class Node
        {
            public Node Parent { get; set; }
            private Node m_child;
            public Node Child
            {
                get { return m_child; }
                set
                {
                    m_child = value;
                    value.Parent = this;
                }
            }
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Title { get; set; }
        }


        internal class Program1
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                Dictionary<int, Node> nodes = new Dictionary<int, Node>()
        {
        {0, new Node() {Id = 0, Title = "Node1"}},
        {1, new Node() {Id = 1, Title = "Node2"}},
        {2, new Node() {Id = 2, Title = "Node7"}},
        {3, new Node() {Id = 3, Title = "Node3"}},
        {4, new Node() {Id = 4, Title = "Node4"}},
        {5, new Node() {Id = 5, Title = "Node5"}},
        {6, new Node() {Id = 6, Title = "Node6"}},
        {7, new Node() {Id = 7, Title = "Node8"}},
        {8, new Node() {Id = 8, Title = "Node9"}},
        {9, new Node() {Id = 9, Title = "Node10"}},
        {10, new Node() {Id = 10, Title = "Node11"}},
        {11, new Node() {Id = 11, Title = "Node12"}},
        {12, new Node() {Id = 12, Title = "Node13"}},
        {13, new Node() {Id = 13, Title = "Node14"}},
        {14, new Node() {Id = 14, Title = "Node15"}},
        {15, new Node() {Id = 15, Title = "Node16"}},
        {16, new Node() {Id = 16, Title = "Node17"}},
        {17, new Node() {Id = 17, Title = "Node18"}},
        {18, new Node() {Id = 18, Title = "Node19"}},
        {19, new Node() {Id = 19, Title = "Node20"}},
        {20, new Node() {Id = 20, Title = "Node21"}},
        {21, new Node() {Id = 21, Title = "Node22"}},
        {22, new Node() {Id = 22, Title = "Node23"}}


    };
            nodes[0].Child = nodes[3];
            nodes[1].Child = nodes[3];
            nodes[2].Child = nodes[4];
            nodes[2].Child = nodes[5];
            nodes[3].Child = nodes[6];
            nodes[3].Child = nodes[7];
            nodes[3].Child = nodes[8];
            nodes[3].Child = nodes[9];
            nodes[6].Child = nodes[10];
            nodes[2].Child = nodes[11];
            nodes[2].Child = nodes[12];
            nodes[7].Child = nodes[13];
            nodes[8].Child = nodes[14];
            nodes[4].Child = nodes[15];
            nodes[5].Child = nodes[15];
            nodes[7].Child = nodes[15];
            nodes[12].Child = nodes[16];
            nodes[13].Child = nodes[16];
            nodes[13].Child = nodes[17];
            nodes[14].Child = nodes[18];
            nodes[8].Child = nodes[19];
            nodes[13].Child = nodes[20];
            nodes[14].Child = nodes[20];
            nodes[8].Child = nodes[21];
            nodes[15].Child = nodes[21];
            nodes[18].Child = nodes[22];
            nodes[19].Child = nodes[22];

            int parentlessNodeCounter = 0;
            Dictionary<int, List<Node>> nbParentNodesDictionary = new Dictionary<int, List<Node>>();
            foreach (KeyValuePair<int, Node> valuePair in nodes)
            {   
                Node parent = valuePair.Value.Parent;
                int nbOfParent = 0;

                if (valuePair.Value.Parent == null)
                    parentlessNodeCounter++;
                while (parent != null)
                {
                    nbOfParent++;
                    parent = parent.Parent;
                }
                if (valuePair.Value.Parent == null && parentlessNodeCounter > 1)
                    nbOfParent ++;
                if (!nbParentNodesDictionary.ContainsKey(nbOfParent))
                {
                    nbParentNodesDictionary[nbOfParent] = new List<Node>();
                }
                nbParentNodesDictionary[nbOfParent].Add(valuePair.Value);
            }

            const int yOffSet = 150;// initial value used for yOffset = 100; 

            foreach (KeyValuePair<int, List<Node>> keyValuePair in nbParentNodesDictionary)
            {
                const int xMax = 1000;// initial value used for xMax = 500; 
                int xOffset = xMax / (keyValuePair.Value.Count + 1);
                int x = 0;
                foreach (Node node in keyValuePair.Value)
                {
                    x += xOffset;
                    Console.Write("id:" + node.Id + " title:" + node.Title + " x:" + x + " y:" + yOffSet * keyValuePair.Key);
                }
            }

        }
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have something like `nodes[0].Child = nodes[3];
            nodes[1].Child = nodes[3];`, This seems that One node (i.e. nodes[3]) has more then one parent (i.e. nodes[0] and nodes[1]). If so, this is not a tree, its a graph :(

Comment: Yes, sorry this is not a tree, rather I should have called it as a map.

Comment: Why you don't keeping parent id inside node??

Comment: @Moumit, to keep it loopy I have done that. So that you can go to the maximum depth.

Comment: Sorry @Artiga .. i did not understand what you want to achieve by this code... what you want to do .. if some node doesn't have parent??

Comment: And one more thing .. if you want to make a tree then why using dictionary as well?

Comment: @Moumit, if the node doesn't have a parent it will come at the top (0- level) here Node1 Node2 and Node7 don't have parents so they will appear at the top.

I am not sure why cant I use dictionary? I mean I should not?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105632/discussion-between-moumit-and-artiga).

Comment: Hi, I have added a possible solution. Please have a look and let me know if it works or needs some more work ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand that you want to calculate `level` for given node. I would suggest not to use `dict`, because you do not need to. You can just add a property `level` calculate level while setting `child`. Here are my major modifications:

```
   internal class Node
    {
      public Node(){
        Level = -1;
        Parents = new List<Node>();
      }
      public List<Node> Parents { get; set; }
      private Node m_child;
      public Node Child
      {
        get { return m_child; }
        set
        {
          m_child = value;
          value.Parents.Add(this);
          m_child.CalculateLevel();
        }
      }
      public int Id { get; set; }
      public string Title { get; set; }
      public int Level {get; private set;}
      public void CalculateLevel(){
        if(Parents.Count() == 0){
          this.Level = 0;
          return;
        }
        foreach (var parent in this.Parents)
        {
           parent.CalculateLevel();
        }

        this.Level = Parents.Select(p => p.Level).Max() + 1;
      }
    }
```

Following is full code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace coordinatesGeneration
{
  class Program
  {
    internal class Node
    {
      public Node(){
        Level = -1;
        Parents = new List<Node>();
      }
      public List<Node> Parents { get; set; }
      private Node m_child;
      public Node Child
      {
        get { return m_child; }
        set
        {
          m_child = value;
          value.Parents.Add(this);
          m_child.CalculateLevel();
        }
      }
      public int Id { get; set; }
      public string Title { get; set; }
      public int Level {get; private set;}
      public void CalculateLevel(){
        if(Parents.Count() == 0){
          this.Level = 0;
          return;
        }
        foreach (var parent in this.Parents)
        {
           parent.CalculateLevel();
        }

        this.Level = Parents.Select(p => p.Level).Max() + 1;
      }
    }


    internal class Program1
    {
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
        Node[] nodes = new Node[]
        {
          new Node() {Id = 0, Title = "Node1"},
          new Node() {Id = 1, Title = "Node2"},
          new Node() {Id = 2, Title = "Node7"},
          new Node() {Id = 3, Title = "Node3"},
          new Node() {Id = 4, Title = "Node4"},
          new Node() {Id = 5, Title = "Node5"},
          new Node() {Id = 6, Title = "Node6"},
          new Node() {Id = 7, Title = "Node8"},
          new Node() {Id = 8, Title = "Node9"},
          new Node() {Id = 9, Title = "Node10"},
          new Node() {Id = 10, Title = "Node11"},
          new Node() {Id = 11, Title = "Node12"},
          new Node() {Id = 12, Title = "Node13"},
          new Node() {Id = 13, Title = "Node14"},
          new Node() {Id = 14, Title = "Node15"},
          new Node() {Id = 15, Title = "Node16"},
          new Node() {Id = 16, Title = "Node17"},
          new Node() {Id = 17, Title = "Node18"},
          new Node() {Id = 18, Title = "Node19"},
          new Node() {Id = 19, Title = "Node20"},
          new Node() {Id = 20, Title = "Node21"},
          new Node() {Id = 21, Title = "Node22"},
          new Node() {Id = 22, Title = "Node23"}


        };
        nodes[0].Child = nodes[3];
        nodes[1].Child = nodes[3];
        nodes[2].Child = nodes[4];
        nodes[2].Child = nodes[5];
        nodes[3].Child = nodes[6];
        nodes[3].Child = nodes[7];
        nodes[3].Child = nodes[8];
        nodes[3].Child = nodes[9];
        nodes[6].Child = nodes[10];
        nodes[2].Child = nodes[11];
        nodes[2].Child = nodes[12];
        nodes[7].Child = nodes[13];
        nodes[8].Child = nodes[14];
        nodes[4].Child = nodes[15];
        nodes[5].Child = nodes[15];
        nodes[7].Child = nodes[15];
        nodes[12].Child = nodes[16];
        nodes[13].Child = nodes[16];
        nodes[13].Child = nodes[17];
        nodes[14].Child = nodes[18];
        nodes[8].Child = nodes[19];
        nodes[13].Child = nodes[20];
        nodes[14].Child = nodes[20];
        nodes[8].Child = nodes[21];
        nodes[15].Child = nodes[21];
        nodes[18].Child = nodes[22];
        nodes[19].Child = nodes[22];

        foreach(var n in nodes){
          Console.WriteLine(n.Title + " (Level: " + n.Level + ") > PARENTS: " + (n.Parents.Count() != 0 ? n.Parents.Count() + " ( " +  (n.Parents.Count() == 1 ? (n.Parents[0].Title + " @ " + n.Parents[0].Level) : n.Parents.Select(p => p.Title + " @ " + p.Level).Aggregate((c,next) => c + ", " + next))  + ")" : "Root") );
        }

      }
    }
  }
}
```

Above code will produce following output.

[image]

So this is how I would calculate `level`. Please let me know if you need anything else!

> NOTE: I have not handled every case. So it would break if you try to set `null` as child.

You can also just loop around each node and call its `CalculateLevel` method like after initialisation and do not call while setting `Child`.

```
foreach(var n in nodes){
  n.CalculateLevel();
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: "Node22" and "Node23" are coming at the same level as that of their parent. For "Node22" the parents are "Node17" and "Node18" and for "Node23" parent is "Node19"

Comment: Let me see. I'll get back to you in a minute.

Comment: Hi, It produces proper output, I printed `parent` and `parent level` as well now.

Comment: `nodes[19].Child = nodes[22];` means, `nodes[22]` i.e. Node23 (because your indexes start with 0, so 22 is 23) in the same way `nodes[19]` is Node20! :) meaning: `Node20` is parent of `Node23`!

Comment: Node23 has two parents Node19 and Node20. and Node19 is at level 4. Please tell me if I am missing something.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105635/discussion-between-dave-amit-and-artiga).

Answer (score 1):

It is done by your approach .. so that you did not have to change existing code ..

```
public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        List<Node> nodes = new List<Node>
        {
          new Node {Id = 0, Title = "Node1"},
          new Node {Id = 1, Title = "Node2"},
          new Node {Id = 2, Title = "Node7"},
          new Node {Id = 3, Title = "Node3"},
          new Node {Id = 4, Title = "Node4"},
          new Node {Id = 5, Title = "Node5"},
          new Node {Id = 6, Title = "Node6"},
          new Node {Id = 7, Title = "Node8"},
          new Node {Id = 8, Title = "Node9"},
          new Node {Id = 9, Title = "Node10"},
          new Node {Id = 10, Title = "Node11"},
          new Node {Id = 11, Title = "Node12"},
          new Node {Id = 12, Title = "Node13"},
          new Node {Id = 13, Title = "Node14"},
          new Node {Id = 14, Title = "Node15"},
          new Node {Id = 15, Title = "Node16"},
          new Node {Id = 16, Title = "Node17"},
          new Node {Id = 17, Title = "Node18"},
          new Node {Id = 18, Title = "Node19"},
          new Node {Id = 19, Title = "Node20"},
          new Node {Id = 20, Title = "Node21"},
          new Node {Id = 21, Title = "Node22"},
          new Node {Id = 22, Title = "Node23"}
      };
        nodes[0].AddChild(nodes[3]);
        nodes[1].AddChild(nodes[3]);
        nodes[2].AddChild(nodes[4]);
        nodes[2].AddChild(nodes[5]);
        nodes[3].AddChild(nodes[6]);
        nodes[3].AddChild(nodes[7]);
        nodes[3].AddChild(nodes[8]);
        nodes[3].AddChild(nodes[9]);
        nodes[6].AddChild(nodes[10]);
        nodes[2].AddChild(nodes[11]);
        nodes[2].AddChild(nodes[12]);
        nodes[7].AddChild(nodes[13]);
        nodes[8].AddChild(nodes[14]);
        nodes[4].AddChild(nodes[15]);
        nodes[5].AddChild(nodes[15]);
        nodes[7].AddChild(nodes[15]);
        nodes[12].AddChild(nodes[16]);
        nodes[13].AddChild(nodes[16]);
        nodes[13].AddChild(nodes[17]);
        nodes[14].AddChild(nodes[18]);
        nodes[8].AddChild(nodes[19]);
        nodes[13].AddChild(nodes[20]);
        nodes[14].AddChild(nodes[20]);
        nodes[8].AddChild(nodes[21]);
        nodes[15].AddChild(nodes[21]);
        nodes[18].AddChild(nodes[22]);
        nodes[19].AddChild(nodes[22]);

        //Get all nodes by level
        //if any node does not have a parent it is by default in level 0

        var rootNodes = nodes.Where(i => i.IsRootElement);

        foreach (var rootNode in rootNodes)
        {
            PrintElementRecurcively(rootNode, null,0);
        }


        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static void PrintElementRecurcively(Node nodeToPrint,Node parentNode,int depth)
    {                 
            System.Console.Write(string.Join("", Enumerable.Repeat("-", (depth*2))));
            System.Console.WriteLine("Node Id:{0}    Level:{1}     ParentId:{2}", nodeToPrint.Id, depth,
                nodeToPrint.Parents == null ? "Unknown" : parentNode.Id.ToString());

            if (nodeToPrint.Childs==null)
            {
                return;
            }

            foreach (var rootNode in nodeToPrint.Childs)
            {
                PrintElementRecurcively(rootNode, nodeToPrint, depth+1);
            }  
    }
}

internal class Node
{
    public List<Node> Parents { get;private set; }         
    public List<Node> Childs{get;private set;}        

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public void AddChild(Node newChild)
    {
        if (Childs == null)
        {
            Childs = new List<Node>();
        }
        Childs.Add(newChild);

        if (newChild.Parents==null)
        {
            newChild.Parents = new List<Node>();
        }
        newChild.Parents.Add(this);            
    }

    public Boolean IsRootElement
    {
        get
        {
            return Parents == null;             
        }
    }

    //public int Level
    //{
    //    get
    //    {
    //        if(Parents==null)
    //        {
    //            return 0;
    //        }

    //        //If you have multiple parents with different level
    //        //then it's impossible to assign that node a fixed level
    //        //you need to took one stategy
    //        // return Parents.Min(i => i.Level)+1;
    //        //return  Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(Parents.Average(i => i.Level)))+1;
    //        return Parents.Max(i => i.Level)+1;
    //    }
    //}



}
```